# Load json-parsed data

Tags: android, json, url

can somebody write me the code to retrieve a JSON array from an url?
It would be nice, I tried it a couple of times and didn't get anywhere with it.
Right now I have no code to show though.

Comment: This is not a trivial problem.  I recommend you check out Volley.  It's a really easy-to-use networking library.

Comment: Write me da codez! It is always nice to give code away for free!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this site for your clarification about JSON and android.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Link only answer, I downvote them